# Playing Video in 4K Resolution Requires Changing Display Settings?

Tags: macos, mac, resolution, 4k-resolution

This may be a silly question, but I wasn't sure. I have a 4K monitor with a graphics card capable of displaying 4K video. However, my default screen resolution is 2K. (I'm on a Mac). Do I have to manually change this resolution to 4K in display settings in order to play a 4K video at full quality say from YouTube?

Thanks.

Comment: If your screen resolution is not 4K then you won't be seeing 4K-worth of pixels on any content. That's how resolution works.

Answer (score 1):

"4K" is a shorthand for a specific resolution, which is a specific number of pixels comprising a screen or graphical content.

If your screen is not actually displaying 4K-worth of pixels, then you will not be seeing 4K-worth of any content you display on that screen.

To see all of the pixels in 4K content you will have to set your screen resolution to 4K.

Answer (score 1):

You can play 'whateverK' video in 'whatever' resolution of monitor.

But it would be down/up scaled.

So if you play 4k video in 2k resolution(although monitor supports 4k), it would be down scaled.

Comment: The question asks how to play the video at 4K.

Answer (score 1):

If the default resolution is set to 2K, the computer will be formating content to 2K and then the monitor will interpolate that onto 4K.  So 4K content will be downscaled on the computer, and the downscaled content will be mapped back to 4K, but you will lose the detail.

If you want to see 4K content at 4K, you need to configure the system's monitor setting to 4K.  Normally, you set the graphics resolution to match the native resolution of the monitor.  The monitor will upscale lower resolution content to fill the screen.

The exception is if you have a small, super-high-resolution screen.  The pixel density gives you a rich, smooth image, with pixels too small to see at normal viewing distances.  That's great for images, but if you are working with text, text will be generated in a "microscopic" size, and a tremendous amount of content will be fit onto the screen that will be too small to use.

You may be able to handle this by setting fonts and icons to a very large size.  That can be a lot of work to set up, sometimes requiring customization and tweaking for each application. Depending on the application, the quality of the results can vary.  Since there is still very little 4K content, the simple approach is to just set the resolution to 2K and use the extra screen resolution to make things smoother.  But then you need to make an exception for actual 4K content.

Answer (score -1):

It won't be perfect until you change the setting. If you use a 4k monitor but set the display setting as 2k, when you watch a 4k video in YouTube, you'll find some image edge over-shapened. You can read this article [4k resolution](https://www.videoproc.com/edit-4k-video/4k-resolution.htm) to know about 4k knowledge and trending.